# How to cache API response in Swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

My API documentation goes in the following series.
 Pre-Oauth API -> getAuthToken API -> Post-Oauth APIs

The post oauth APIs contain access token in the authorization header. Is it possible to cache the access token value in swagger and use it in that session for post oauth APIs?

Comment: Are you asking about caching the access token in swagger-ui, swagger-codegen or other swagger tools?

Comment: @wing328 It is about caching in swagger-ui